# I want to execute ng-click function via console,is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome

I want to call `ng-click` function using `console`. Is it possible?

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-green ng-binding" id="login-button"ng-click="onLoginClick($event)">Log In</button>
```

Comment: If not, then there are other ways to test `onLoginClick`, right?

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
angular.element('#login-button').triggerHandler('click');
```

this will work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript getelementbyid as following:

```
document.getElementById("login-button").click();
```

Comment: this is out of context. the question is about get the click event in angularjs.

Comment: @Nach this did not work for me, can you please help? It is giving me undefined!

Answer (score 0):

The only way it comes to my mind to do it is using jQuery to select the element (button) and then trigger the click:

```
$( "#login-button" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Try it and let us know if it works, here you are a JSFiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vhbazan/mesg71ww/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can invoke/execute a function using `window.function_name()` or `function_name()`